# Signalr: JavaScript client failing to reconnect on IE (parseerror exception)

Tags: javascript, .net, signalr

**Configuration/Setup:**

- Windows 7 64bit, .Net 4.5, Visual Studio 2012
- Self-Host Signalr Server (console app)
- JavaScript client

**Background:**

I started with [this self host tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-signalr-self-host) as my base with the end goal of configuring a hub server that I can connect to across domains (CORS). I'm using mostly version 2.0.0-rc1.

**Repo Steps:**

The repo steps are easy. Navigate to the test page (default.html) from good 'ol IE (version 10) and wait.

Here are the signalr client logs detailing what happens:

```
[21:47:30 PDT] SignalR: Auto detected cross domain url. 
 [21:47:30 PDT] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'selfieserver'. 
 [21:47:30 PDT] SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'. 
 [21:47:31 PDT] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAAIkua2h4902EBFsaUr1NkAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADId6sPY7u1b7U4MSyyjEGgAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAPbquY3AwSaeBDURBcXbiv8oAAAA5cpbDNk5rm0qDdq6nDWpqiazmTL4R%2Bv%2FI%2FSzcW1eAI71AkllpeDIKxQAAAAfYvObLT5lU2OeXpUvdjR%2B%2BLpotQ%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&tid=8'. 
 [21:47:31 PDT] SignalR: Long poll complete. 
 [21:47:31 PDT] SignalR: LongPolling connected. 
 [21:47:31 PDT] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAAIkua2h4902EBFsaUr1NkAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADId6sPY7u1b7U4MSyyjEGgAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAPbquY3AwSaeBDURBcXbiv8oAAAA5cpbDNk5rm0qDdq6nDWpqiazmTL4R%2Bv%2FI%2FSzcW1eAI71AkllpeDIKxQAAAAfYvObLT5lU2OeXpUvdjR%2B%2BLpotQ%3D%3D&messageId=d-4213A9B0-B%2C0%7CU%2C0%7CV%2C1%7CW%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&tid=4'. 
 [21:48:01 PDT] SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = parsererror.  Response = undefined. 
 [21:48:04 PDT] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAAIkua2h4902EBFsaUr1NkAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADId6sPY7u1b7U4MSyyjEGgAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAPbquY3AwSaeBDURBcXbiv8oAAAA5cpbDNk5rm0qDdq6nDWpqiazmTL4R%2Bv%2FI%2FSzcW1eAI71AkllpeDIKxQAAAAfYvObLT5lU2OeXpUvdjR%2B%2BLpotQ%3D%3D&messageId=d-4213A9B0-B%2C0%7CU%2C0%7CV%2C1%7CW%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&tid=0'. 
 [21:48:05 PDT] SignalR: Raising the reconnect event 
 [21:48:35 PDT] SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = parsererror.  Response = undefined. 
 [21:48:38 PDT] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAAIkua2h4902EBFsaUr1NkAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADId6sPY7u1b7U4MSyyjEGgAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAPbquY3AwSaeBDURBcXbiv8oAAAA5cpbDNk5rm0qDdq6nDWpqiazmTL4R%2Bv%2FI%2FSzcW1eAI71AkllpeDIKxQAAAAfYvObLT5lU2OeXpUvdjR%2B%2BLpotQ%3D%3D&messageId=d-4213A9B0-B%2C0%7CU%2C0%7CV%2C1%7CW%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&tid=1'. 
 [21:48:41 PDT] SignalR: Raising the reconnect event 
 [21:49:08 PDT] SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = parsererror.  Response = undefined. 
 [21:49:11 PDT] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAAIkua2h4902EBFsaUr1NkAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADId6sPY7u1b7U4MSyyjEGgAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAPbquY3AwSaeBDURBcXbiv8oAAAA5cpbDNk5rm0qDdq6nDWpqiazmTL4R%2Bv%2FI%2FSzcW1eAI71AkllpeDIKxQAAAAfYvObLT5lU2OeXpUvdjR%2B%2BLpotQ%3D%3D&messageId=d-4213A9B0-B%2C0%7CU%2C0%7CV%2C1%7CW%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&tid=7'. 
 [21:49:18 PDT] SignalR: Raising the reconnect event 
 [21:49:42 PDT] SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = parsererror.  Response = undefined. 
 [21:49:45 PDT] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAAIkua2h4902EBFsaUr1NkAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADId6sPY7u1b7U4MSyyjEGgAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAPbquY3AwSaeBDURBcXbiv8oAAAA5cpbDNk5rm0qDdq6nDWpqiazmTL4R%2Bv%2FI%2FSzcW1eAI71AkllpeDIKxQAAAAfYvObLT5lU2OeXpUvdjR%2B%2BLpotQ%3D%3D&messageId=d-4213A9B0-B%2C0%7CU%2C0%7CV%2C1%7CW%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&tid=9'. 
 [21:50:00 PDT] SignalR: Raising the reconnect event 
 [21:50:15 PDT] SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = parsererror.  Response = undefined. 
 [21:50:18 PDT] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://localhost:8889/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE%2FCl%2BsBAAAAAIkua2h4902EBFsaUr1NkAAAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADId6sPY7u1b7U4MSyyjEGgAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAPbquY3AwSaeBDURBcXbiv8oAAAA5cpbDNk5rm0qDdq6nDWpqiazmTL4R%2Bv%2FI%2FSzcW1eAI71AkllpeDIKxQAAAAfYvObLT5lU2OeXpUvdjR%2B%2BLpotQ%3D%3D&messageId=d-4213A9B0-B%2C0%7CU%2C0%7CV%2C1%7CW%2C0&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22selfieserver%22%7D%5D&tid=8'. 
 [21:50:45 PDT] SignalR: Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout (30000ms), disconnecting. 
 [21:50:45 PDT] SignalR: Stopping connection. 
 [21:50:45 PDT] SignalR: Aborted xhr requst.
```

You can see that errors keep occurring and the client keeps reconnecting until the re-connection fails.

As a bonus, I've created a repro app that you can download from skydrive [here](http://sdrv.ms/13mj2mP)

If anyone has some insight to my issue or can point me in the right direct, it would make my day.

**[UPDATE]**
Of the 5 devs that have tried to reproduce via the included source code, zero have been able to reproduce.

I'm assuming at this point my problem is specific to my machine (duh?). With this assumption, what environmental element could be causing the  signalr/poll?transport=longPolling request to "abort"?

Comment: Are you running any sort of anti-virus software at all? We've seen that cause issues in some cases with long running HTTP requests. In this case the long poll is failing because the response returned is not valid JSON (or blank), which obviously shouldn't happen but some layer between your browser & the server may be interfering.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1557

Note the comment from the author:
"This isn't a bug. It's the intended design we chose. Changing this to a suggestion."

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Visual Studio as Administrator? It might have to do with permissions and Owin.